# Let $A$ be an abelian group s.t. $\forall n\in\Bbb N, [n]:A\rightarrow A: a\mapsto n\cdot a$ is surjective. What can we say about $A$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group such that for any natural number $n\neq 0$ the multiplication  $[n]:A\rightarrow A: a\mapsto n\cdot a$ is surjective. What can we say about $A$ ?

Comment: This is almost the definition of a divisible group. I don't know what else you'd want to say about that besides the classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are exactly (by definition) the [**divisible groups**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group). Divisible groups have a number of nice properties, some of which [are mentioned at the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Properties).